springboot application needs to connect AWS RDS postgres database
I have a springboot application which runs locally for now. But plans to move EC2 or ECS. I am trying to connect AWS RDS postgres from my springboot application. RDS postgres is in private VPC which have few security groups rule configured. So what configuration i need to do now to access AWS postgres from my local and also from EC2/ECS.
Note: when i try to connect with normal springboot datasource configuration with url, uname, password and drivername, i am getting error tomcat start up error mentioning having unsatisfied dependencies.

The RDS instance is in a private subnet, so it can only be accessed by other things in the same VPC. The Java app running on your local computer won't be able to access it, because it has no network route to the RDS instance.

@MarkB Thanks for your input. Now Is there any configuration that i can do to access RDS from my local.

It's unclear what you are asking for. Are you asking for how to reconfigure the RDS instance to make it public?

"unsatisfied dependencies"?  It sounds like that issue should be solved first.

To allow remote access to your RDS (including from a localhost on a workstation), you must first allow remote connections to the VPC that the RDS is in.
If you haven't done so, add a gateway to your VPC then create and assign a public subnet. You then need to modify your RDS networking configuration to use the new subnet. See this AWS question for more information
Also, make sure that you have marked the database as publically available (RDS -> Connectivity & Security -> Security -> Publicily Accessible)
Before trying to connect to the RDS remotely with your Spring Boot application, troubleshoot connections using the psql client on your local machine.
From AWS RDS docs
psql \
   --host=<DB instance endpoint> \
   --port=<port> \
   --username=<master username> \
   --password \
   --dbname=<database name> 

That said, it is not recommended to have your RDS database accessible to the public without having a strict security group and IAM policies configured and tested.
An alternative for development is to run a local Postgres server on your workstation. If you already have Docker or Docker Desktop (or Podman), it takes just a few minutes to get a Postgres container up and running. Even installing it directly on your machine is usually a streamlined process.
Alternatively, if you already have an EC2 instance set up in AWS that has access to the RDS, then you can access it from your workstation via SSH forwarding.
